# jquery lightbox working on one page, but not another on same site

Tags: javascript, jquery, image, lightbox

A programmer installed jquery lightbox and everything was working fine on

http://www.ozhiphopshop.com.au/sub_photos.php?id=11

I wanted to use the exact same effect for the one image on

http://www.ozhiphopshop.com.au/product_detail.php?pro_id=69

In the included header file I've changed the changed the following script (which is working fine on the first page):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
$('#gallery a').lightBox();
$('#gallery1 a').lightBox();
});
</script>
```

to:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
$('a.pro_img').lightbox();
});
</script>
```

but that doesn't seem to work. And the linked file is opening in a new window.

The div class for the file I want the lightbox to work with is 'pro_img' which is why I made the change the way I did.
I've made no changes to the css or the js files, which may be where I'm going wrong.

I'm not a programmer, so I've just been trying to reverse engineer what was done on the first page. I'm really interested in learning more about programming, hence the reason I'm doing it myself.

I've noticed the same question on here, but none of the answers seemed to relate to exactly what I'm dealing with.

Any help would be appreciated.

All the best,
Michael

Comment: If you are interested in programming, please don't start by modifying live sites. Leave that for programmers (even if you have to pay them...). You will just create more problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change

```
$('a.pro_img').lightbox();
```

to

```
$('div.pro_img a').lightbox();
```

Comment: hell yes! can i seriously send you a bottle of wine or carton of beer or something?!

Comment: How about you be my valentine!? :D

Comment: i'll check with my wife. 
but she's pretty easy going, so i think you have a deal :)